# Translating line from sql server to oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am slightly confused with the way to_char works in oracle. How would you translate this sql server line into oracle?

```
cast(month(date) as varchar)+'/'+cast(day(date) as varchar)+'/'+cast(year(date) as varchar)
```

Comment: Your title says `translate from oracle to sql server` and your question says `translate from sql server to oracle`.  Which is it?

Comment: Yes! So sorry. Just corrected it, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use this:

```
select to_char(date_column,'MM/dd/yyyy') from your_table;
```

You should read more about **`to_char`** in [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) or [techonthenet](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php). You will find it easy to understand.

Comment: Hum I had been messing up on something quite silly. Thank you